# In Expression Engine How we can avoid same ip address again from entry views tracking

Tags: ee2, channel-entries

In expression engine for different channel titles different view count is there .But how we can avoid same ip address again from view count.

Answer (score 1):

The EE template count doesn't filter on individual IPs, or not count duplicate IPs. You're better off using Google's webmaster tools and use their tracking when it comes to page counts.